# JSCharting - Drag and Drop - Organizational Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to implement a drag and drop event on the nodes to re-order the `parent` of the nodes, possibly using JQuery or JavaScript?

**Please check below the example:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Arrow Layout Organizational Chart | JSCharting</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text-html; charset=utf-8" />

<script src="https://code.jscharting.com/latest/jscharting.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jscharting.com/latest/modules/types.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jscharting.com/latest/modules/toolbar.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" />

    <style>
      .chartDiv {
        margin: 8px auto;
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chartDiv1" class="chartDiv" style="max-width: 700px;height: 400px;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      /*
Org chart interactive orientation with padded connector line arrow layout.
Learn how to:

  - Manage organizational chart layout when changing orientation.
*/
      // JS
      var chart = JSC.chart('chartDiv1', {
        debug: true,
        type: 'organizational',

        /* These options will apply to all annotations including point nodes and breadcrumbs. */
        defaultAnnotation: { padding: [5, 10], margin: [15, 5] },
        defaultTooltip_enabled: false,

        defaultSeries: {
          color: '#dde1e8',
          defaultPoint: {
            label_maxWidth: 90,
            /* Default line styling for connector lines */
            connectorLine: {
              /* No radius on first angle, then 5px on the second angle. */
              radius: [0, 5],
              color: '#424242',
              width: 1,
              caps: { end: { type: 'arrow', size: 6 } }
            }
          }
        },
        series: [
          {
            points: [
              { x: 'Project Manager', id: 'PM' },
              { x: 'Deputy Project Manager', id: 'DPM', parent: 'PM' },
              { x: 'System Engineering', id: 'SE', parent: 'DPM' },
              { x: 'Independent Test Group', id: 'ITG', parent: 'DPM' },
              { x: 'Project Technical Lead', id: 'PTL', parent: 'DPM' },
              { x: 'Quality Assurance', id: 'QA', parent: 'DPM' },
              { x: 'Configuration Manager', id: 'CM', parent: 'DPM' },

              { x: 'S/W Subproject Manager 1', id: 'SM1', parent: 'PTL' },
              { x: 'Team 1', id: 'team11', parent: 'SM1' },
              { x: 'Team 2', id: 'team12', parent: 'SM1' },
              { x: 'Team 3', id: 'team13', parent: 'SM1' },

              { x: 'S/W Subproject Manager 2', id: 'SM2', parent: 'PTL' },
              { x: 'Team 1', id: 'team21', parent: 'SM2' },
              { x: 'Team 2', id: 'team22', parent: 'SM2' },

              { x: 'S/W Subproject Manager 3', id: 'SM3', parent: 'PTL' },
              { x: 'Team 1', id: 'team31', parent: 'SM3' },
              { x: 'Team 2', id: 'team32', parent: 'SM3' }
            ]
          }
        ],

        toolbar: {
          defaultItem: {
            margin: 5,
            events_click: orientChart
          },
          items: {
            Left_icon: 'system/default/zoom/arrow-left',
            Right_icon: 'system/default/zoom/arrow-right',
            Down_icon: 'system/default/zoom/arrow-down',
            Up_icon: 'system/default/zoom/arrow-up'
          }
        }
      });

      function orientChart(direction) {
        var isVertical = /up|down/.test(direction.toLowerCase());
        chart.options({
          type: 'organizational ' + direction,
          defaultPoint_annotation: {
            syncWidth: !isVertical,
            syncHeight: isVertical,
            margin: isVertical ? [15, 5] : [5, 15]
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: as per I checked the library they didn't provide this option so you have to it by yourself.Or try to check any other library which provide you drag-drop facility

Comment: https://balkan.app/OrgChartJS/Docs/DragAndDrop